# How to append Query Result in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently working a school project based on database application. Im using MS Access 2016 to do this.

So the database system is about cinema ticketing system.

Currently I'm stuck at this situation:

1. I have a movie list.

Table : MOVIES
Attr: MovieID, MovieName, Genre, Rating, MoviePic

2. This movie list have their respective showtime

Table: SHOWTIMES
Attr: Time, MovieID, HallID

3. One movie can have many showtimes
4. So, once I click a movie, I will have a window showing their respective showtime.
5. When the showtime window open, I will have a button that say "Select this showtime"
6. So, to booked a showtime, I create a new table called "Booked Showtime"

Table : BOOKED SHOWTIMES
Attr: MovieID, Time, HallID

7. So, how to append user selected showtime to the "Booked Showtime" table?

Actually the "Showtime" window that open when I clicked at a movie is a query as it will show showtime for the clicked movie..thats why the title of the question is "..append query result.."..I need to know how to append to the "Booked Showtime" table based onthe query result of the showtime..

currently I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO [BOOKED SHOWTIMES] ( [Time], MovieID, HallID )
SELECT SHOWTIMES.Time, SHOWTIMES.MovieID, SHOWTIMES.HallID
FROM CUSTOMERS, SHOWTIMES INNER JOIN [BOOKED SHOWTIMES] ON SHOWTIMES.Time = [BOOKED SHOWTIMES].Time
WHERE (((SHOWTIMES.Time)=[Forms]![SHOW SHOWTIME]![Time]) AND ((SHOWTIMES.MovieID)=[Forms]![SHOW SHOWTIME]![MovieID]) AND ((SHOWTIMES.HallID)=[Forms]![SHOW SHOWTIME]![HallID]));
```

so the query above didnt work as nothing ( You are about to append 0 rows ) is added to the "Booked Showtimes" table...

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can use a normal insert query, and not `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO [BOOKED SHOWTIMES] ( [Time], MovieID, HallID )
VALUES([Forms]![SHOW SHOWTIME]![Time], [Forms]![SHOW SHOWTIME]![MovieID], [Forms]![SHOW SHOWTIME]![HallID])
```

However, I can't see the relevance of the customers table, and it looks like you're doing nothing with that table.